# .Net 2.0 on OSX with WineHQ?

Tags: macos, .net-framework, wine, darwine

[This page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3754) doesn't mention OSX, but the WineHQ stuff in general does. Does anyone know if there's any reason that .Net 2.0 cannot be run on OSX with Wine? Has anybody tried it?

Answer (score 0):

I've run .NET applications on my mac using the mono framework (without WINE) which provides the Common Language Runtime for the MAC. Not perfect but might be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, I'm all over the mono framework and have ported my app to work on Mono Winforms. It's okay but not great. I'm interested in this Wine thing, now.